# Python - Head or Tail Exercise

Tags: python

I need a small tips to finished this exercise.
The program should display head or tail after the for loop generate a sequence of 0 and 1. This module contains a number of random number generators:

```
import random

# function to determine head or tail of printed random number
def flip(coin):
    # if the coin is zero, then print head
    if coin == 0:
        print("heads!")
    # else print tail
    else:
        print("Tail!")
# simple repeat loop that calls flip() 10 times to generate a random
# sequence of 10 heads and tails
def main():
     for coin in range(10):
        print (random.randrange(2))

main()
```

Comment: You didn't call `flip()` function...

Comment: `random.choice(["heads!","tails!"])` and forgetting the inner loop would make more sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to call the flip function.  Also I would recommend using random.randint()

```
import random

#function to determine head or tail of printed random number
def flip(coin):
    #if the coin is zero, then print head
    if coin == 0:
        print("heads!")
    #else print tail
    else:
        print("Tail!")
#simple repeat loop that calls flip() 10 times to generate a random
#sequence of 10 heads and tails
def main():
     for coin in range(10):
        flip(random.randint(0, 1))

main()
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to *call* the `flip` function, passing it the result of that `random.randrange(2)` call:

```
print (flip(random.randrange(2)))
```

As Padraic points out in comments, your code will also output `None`, because it's printing the returned value from the called function, and no `return` statement produces an implicit `None`. You can fix this in one of two ways: either have `flip` return the result instead of printing it, or call it without printing.

```
if coin == 0:
    return "heads!"
# else print tail
else:
    return "Tail!"
```

or:

```
flip(random.randrange(2))
```

Comment: I'm sure that this also is a dupe question :P

Comment: This is also going to print None

Comment: Thanks...Since, i remove the print from it...It gives the exact answer.